# Odoo - Call model function in domain filter for tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using odoo 10e. I want to build a dynamic domain filter for my tree view and for that i want to call a function in domain filter so that i can update filter from my model function accordingly.

I tried to create records rules also tried to create server action and when i create server action it doesn't call model class function. It says `self` is not defined while evaluating. Considering that in action field i am giving this `self.custom_domain_function`